# sql : find the lowest amount of loan at each branch

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, aggregate-functions

what does mean by this question ? I am confused . Does it say to find the lowest amount or the branch names who have the lowest amount . Help me to figure this out .

My_query(finding the lowest amount) :

```
select min(total_amount) 
from (select branch_name ,sum(amount) as total_amount 
       from loan group by branch_name );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking the community members to tell you what a question means - when we aren't even seeing the question? I understand showing the question may be difficult (it may not be in English), but still... Can't you ask your teacher/instructor or your manager/boss, whoever gave you this question?

Comment: its a assignment work given by my instructor . As i'm confused about what does it mean , i just wanted to be clear about that . That's it .

Answer (score 4):

I think the question is asking for the smallest loan made at each branch.  In this case you can use the following query:

```
SELECT branch_name,
       MIN(amount) as smallest_loan
FROM loan
GROUP BY branch_name
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution will consider the total loan amount at each branch, and it will select the one with the least total (showing the branch name and the least total amount). It assumes there are no "ties" for last place; if there are, it only shows the first one in alphabetical order.

```
select  min(branch_name) keep(dense_rank first over sum(amount)) as branch_name,
        min(sum(amount)) as least_total_loan_amount
from   loan
group by branch_name;
```

If all you need is the smallest amount (but not the bank name), you can simply delete the first column (everything from `min(branch...` to `as branch_name,` including the comma).